Physical pendulum: axis of rotation
Why is the angular momentum always considered to be parallel to the angular velocity in physical pendulum problems, as if the axis of rotation were a principal axis always? I don't see the justification for writing always $L = I \omega$ and taking the derivative to equate with the torque.

There's not a single angular momentum for a system.   We can calculate a consistent angular momentum about any point/axis.
However, it is often a convenience for us to pick a point/axis where some of the forces can be ignored because they contribute no torque.
For a pendulum, taking the angular momentum about the rotational axis means that the tension from the hinge will exert no torque.

According to German wikipedia (English one contains equivalent formulas but without the nice matrix visualization.) The moment of inertia $\Theta$ for the calculation of angular momentum with reference to the coordinate origin of a point mass $m$ with distance $\vec{r}$ to the coordinate origin can be written as:
$$\Rightarrow\Theta = m\,\begin{pmatrix}
  (r_2^2+r_3^2) & -r_1 r_2       & -r_1 r_3\\
 -r_1 r_2       &  (r_1^2+r_3^2)   & -r_2 r_3\\
 -r_1 r_3       & -r_2 r_3       &  (r_1^2+r_2^2) \end{pmatrix} \\$$
By symmetry consideration it can be seen, and confirmed by looking at the formula, that you will have 1 principle axis with eigenvalue $0$ in direction of $\vec{r}$. All other axis perpendicular to $\vec{r}$ will also be principle axis with eigenvalue $mr^2$. Therefore the axis of rotation for a pendulum consisting of a point mass and a rigid massless rod will always be a principle axis of rotation, if the rod moves inside the rotation plane.
